# Visualizing a topological example.

Tags: algebraic-topology

I am trying to " see" the result of doing the disjoint union of two solid tori, with their boundaries identified .Any help?

Comment: Are they being identified with an identity mapping?

Comment: Good question!I didn't realice. Yes, with the identity...

Comment: The links on [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/214251/representation-of-s3-as-the-union-of-two-solid-tori) mathse question might be useful to you. I'm not saying it directly answers your question, but they might be helpful in how you can think of gluing solid tori. I don't know myself.

Answer (score 2):

Visualize it as a solid but transparent torus silvered on the boundary.

A ray inside the torus would strike the silvered boundary and "reflect" into the second torus. Each internal reflection would be regarded as the ray passing into the other torus.