# The fundamental group of $S^3-S^1$

Tags: algebraic-topology

How can I calculate the fundamental group of $S^3-S^1$? I believe it might be similar to the fundamental group of $S^2-S^0$ which is $ \Bbb Z$ but I'm having trouble showing it. Is this the right direction (showing it's $\Bbb Z$) or am I way off?

Comment: What direction?

Comment: I'm trying to show it's $\Bbb Z$

Comment: It is $\mathbb Z$, but you did not give any hint as to *how* you think youy are going to prove it.

Comment: I wasn't sure it was. I was trying to show it deformation retracts to ${\Bbb R}^2-{x}$

Comment: Since it does not contain $\mathbb R^2-\text{pt}$, it can't!

Comment: Poor choice of words on my part. I'm sorry. I wast trying to show it's homeomorphic to the plane minus point. And then deformation retract to the circle

Comment: It is not homeomorphic to the plane minus a point: it is a $3$-dimensional manifold.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One can write $S^3$ as the [union of two solid tori](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/214251/representation-of-s3-as-the-union-of-two-solid-tori/214750). Using this, it is easy to see that the complement of a standard $S^1$ in $S^3$ deformation retracts onto a solid torus.

Since a solid torus deformation retracts onto its central $S^1$, the fundamental group of your space is $\mathbb Z$.

Alternatively, if you consider the stereographic projection $S^3-\{P\}\to\mathbb R^3$ from the sphere from a point $P$ in your $S^1$, then the image of the $S^1$ is a line in $\mathbb R^3$. You this get a homeo of $S^3-S^1$ to $\mathbb R^3-\text{line}$. (For this to work, the $S^1$ has to be a maximal circle of $S^3$)

Comment: Yes the edit was what I was trying to do. Thanks

Answer (score 6):

Here is a cute visualization. You can think of $S^3$ as the one-point compactification of $\mathbb{R}^3$, so as $\mathbb{R}^3$ together with a "point at infinity." So for starters you can visualize a circle in $\mathbb{R}^3$, keeping in mind that there is a point at infinity, and wanting to figure out the fundamental group of its complement.

But now you can send a point on the circle to infinity, since you were going to remove the circle anyway! This straightens out the circle to a line (if it helps, visualize the analogous construction for $S^2$), so your space is now the complement of a line $\mathbb{R}$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$. This is clearly $\mathbb{R}$ times $\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus \{ 0 \}$, so is homotopy equivalent to a circle $S^1$.